# Abrir archivo docx en AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio, ms-word

Estoy intentando abrir un archivo Word, con extensión docx, pero al presionar el botón que lo abre, se cierra la app. Os paso el código:

```
public void buttonOpenFile(View view)  {

File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator, "Factura.docx");

try {
      Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
      Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      fileIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      fileIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/msword");
      startActivity(fileIntent);
     } 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cant Find Your File",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

¿Podéis por favor indicarme donde podría estar el bloqueo?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Y que dice el logcat?